# Resampling 1 min data to 15 min giving key errors of Range Index or Index

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert 1 min data to 15 min.The data is in format of Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume.

I was getting this error: " TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex' "
Then I searched on Stackoverflow and used this function to add an index.
data.set_index(data['Date'], inplace=True)
But now I am getting this error: "TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'"

This is the code:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('Tatasteel')
data.set_index(data['Date'], inplace=True)
date = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])


data['Open'] = data.resample('15Min')['Open'].first()
data['High'] = data.resample('15Min')['High'].max()
data['Low'] = data.resample('15Min')['Low'].min()
data['Close'] = data.resample('15Min')['Close'].last()
data['Volume'] = data.resample('15Min')['Volume'].sum()

print(data.head())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `DatetimeIndex` by `index_col` and `parse_dates` parameters and then instead assign to same columns create new DataFrame by aggregate functions:

```
data = pd.read_csv('Tatasteel', index_col='Date', parse_dates=['Date'])

df = data.resample('15Min').agg({'Open': 'first',
                                 'High': 'max',
                                 'Low': 'min',
                                 'Close': 'last',
                                 'Volume': 'sum'})
```